# How to reduce logout time [Angular js]

Tags: angularjs, networking, server

I have a simple logout function but locally it just takes 1 second to logout while on server its taking 6 second. How can I reduce the logout time.

```
 $scope.SignOut = function() {

        $rootScope.globalSession = null;
        $rootScope.globalManagerViewDisplayFlag = false;
        $rootScope.globalAdminViewDisplayFlag = false;
        $rootScope.globalSuperViewDisplayFlag = false;
        $cookieStore.remove('Session');
        $cookieStore.remove('WeAlertUserData');
       // $location.path('/login');
        $window.location.reload();
    };
});
```

This is my main Index page.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="W-Alert">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/permission-ng.js"></script> 
    <script src="libs/transition/TransitionEventNames.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/transition/TransitionEvents.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-permission.js"></script> 
    <script src="libs/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-uuid2.min.js"></script>

    <!--Spinner-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/spin.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-spinner.js"></script>
    <!-- Toaster -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/checklist-model.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/angular-toastr.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>
<!-- 
    <script src="js/config.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/dirPagination.js"></script>
    <script src="js/constants.js"></script>

    <!-- change password controller-->
    <script src="components/change-password/change-password-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="components/change-password/change-password-service.js"></script>

    <!-- auth controller-->
    <script src="components/authentication/authenticate-service.js"></script>
    <script src="components/authentication/authenticate-controller.js"></script>
    <!--client -->
    <script src="components/client/client-service.js"></script>
    <script src="components/client/client-controller.js"></script>
    <!--manager-->
    <script src="components/manager/manager-service.js"></script>
    <script src="components/manager/manager-controller.js"></script>

    <!--application-->
    <script src="components/application/application-service.js"></script>
    <script src="components/application/application-controller.js"></script>

    <!--group-->
    <script src="components/group/group-service.js"></script>
    <script src="components/group/group-controller.js"></script>

    <!--user-->
    <script src="components/user/user-service.js"></script>
    <script src="components/user/user-controller.js"></script>

    <!--client profile-->
    <script src="components/profile/profile-controller.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link href="bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/w-alert.css" />

</head>
<body >
    <span us-spinner="{radius:30, width:8, length: 16}" spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>
    <ng-include src="'layout/shell.htm'"/>    

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
    <script src="bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** Server is in another country. Does this matters? If it does then what can I do to reduce the time?

Comment: This seem like a network related question which make it off-topic to SO. There can be many reasons for that - Slow queries to the DB, low performances server and more. You need to investigate it on the server side, not the client side

Comment: Server side is made in WSO2. How can I investigate on that side because it not any http call while logging out.

Comment: What line is taking the most time ?

Comment: Oh, I thought there was an ajax call. I'll try to think and write back if I have a different suggestion

Comment: I check in chrome development tool, login.html and logo image is taking most time and ng-include src="'layout/shell.htm'"

Comment: no its just removing the session.